# Add Original Date to Pivot Table DataFeed

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Is there a way to add a data to an Excel datafeed pivot table the first time that a unique item appears and retain that date following future updates to the data?

I am monitoring a data feed to see when new items appear on it.  I would like to be able to filter on blocks of time and see what new data was added in that period but if I add a column with the function Now(), for example, it will reset every single time that I refresh the data.

Comment: Did my answer below resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Put your Item in the Rows area, and also add it to the Values field as a Count. Then add your Date field to the values area as a Min. That will show you the first time any item appears.

If you are only interested in items where multiple of the same item have been sold, then additionally set a Values filter on your Item in the Rows filter so that only counts above one show:
[image]